# iphone uiaccessiblity multiple languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accessibility

I've been doing reading about VoiceOver on iPhone, but I can't find anyone talking about how to mark content as a certain language and use more than one language in an app.  I want to make my dictionary VoiceOver compatible.

For example this can be written in a UITableViewCell (English then German) and VoiceOver will read this line with two different voices:

to drink - trinken

If this is not possible, then VoiceOver users cannot use any content that has more than one language at a time.

Comment: It doesn't seem like VoiceOver is the right technology to use here.  VoiceOver is intended to provide user's feedback in their native language, which is what makes it accessible.  For multiple languages it seems like you'll actually want to have a  root language string, and a localized version of that string which are both spoken using native accents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has defined a protocol, see the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html), named `UIAccessibility` which is implemented by all views in `UIKit`. The protocol defines the property `accessibilityLanguage` which sets the language of an element. The default is to return `nil` which is interpreted as the user's default language.

As far as single views are concerned it seems impossible to choose two different languages at the same time. However, it seems to be possible to declare two separate views (one with an English, the other one with, let's say, a German label) and override the above method for both views, returning different languages for both. This way you can effectively use two different languages with VoiceOver in your application.

Comment: So I'm guessing a UIWebView can only have one language attribute.  It seems that if I mark different language elements within HTML specs http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/langtag.html that VoiceOver will not recognize them.

Comment: @ojreadmore: Although I have not tried that for a `UIWebView` this is also my interpretation. Splitting up the webview into two (or more) subviews should do the trick, but for web views you certainly would need to parse the HTML source code yourself. And having scrollable content is a whole different story, it might not be helpful for a visually impaired user. Maybe it makes sense to submit this as a feature request to Apple.

Comment: My initial testing with UIWebView looks promising.  So far using the iPhone Simulator and the accessibility inspector, the HTML tags are being recognized with different languages.  I still need to test using a generation 4 device.

Comment: @ojreadmore: I have just tried it on a 4th generation iPod Touch. Safari indeed respects the choice of language that the website specifies and properly reads all text, even on pages with content in multiple languages. So no need to worry about parsing the HTML. That is indeed a pleasant surprise!